# No route matches {:action=>"show".... :controller = " posts" }

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following an [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/start-your-seo-right-with-sitemaps-on-rails/) to test sitemap generation. The article didn't mention anything about writing `show` action. But since I started to get this error, I even wrote a simple `show` action.  Following is my posts controller:

```
def index
  @posts= Post.all
end

def show
 @posts = Post.all
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :categories do
      resources :posts
    end
    root to: 'pages#index'
end
```

**sitemap.rb**

```
 Category.find_each do |category|
    add category_posts_path(category), :changefreq => 'weekly', :lastmod => category.updated_at

    category.posts.each do |post|
      add category_post_path(category), :changefreq => 'yearly', :lastmod => post.updated_at
    end
  end
```

And when I run `rake sitemap:refresh` , it's giving following:

```
In '/home/mypc/Projects/sitemaptest/public/':
rake aborted!
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>#<Category id: 1, title: "Surprised by Joy", created_at: "2017-04-07 09:13:52", updated_at: "2017-04-07 09:13:52">, :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed `post` param at:

```
category.posts.each do |post|
  add category_post_path(category), :changefreq => 'yearly', :lastmod => post.updated_at
end
```

Its should be:

```
 category.posts.each do |post|
   add category_post_path(category, post), :changefreq => 'yearly', :lastmod => post.updated_at
 end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this:

```
 Category.find_each do |category|
    add category_posts_path(category), :changefreq => 'weekly', :lastmod => category.updated_at

    category.posts.each do |post|
      add category_post_path(category, post), :changefreq => 'yearly', :lastmod => post.updated_at
    end
  end
```

You are missing post object and it is `nested` routes that's why getting `missing required keys: [:id]` issue.